# Meaning of dividing every side of congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

When I am faced with the following:

$15 \equiv x$ (mod 10)

Ignore the simplicity of this. What I am interested is is the following in any way connected to the solution for $x$:

$\frac{15}{5} \equiv \frac{x}{5}$ (mod 2)

The congruence was divided by $5$. Does solving this for $x$ in any way connect to the first congruence?

Comment: May be useful - $$ax\equiv ay\pmod m\iff x\equiv y\left(\bmod \frac m{\text{gcd}(a,m)}\right) $$

Comment: So $x$ would be $1$ but it is not $1$ in the first congruence.

Comment: I know about this, but that $x$ is then a soultion in different modulo.

Answer (score 1):

$x \equiv ca \pmod{\!cn}\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid x,\ $  so  $\,\ c(x/c)\equiv ca \pmod{\!cn} \iff x/c \equiv  a \pmod{\! n}$

because $\,cn\mid cX-ca\iff n\mid X-a,\,$ since $\ \dfrac{cX-ca}{cn} = \dfrac{X-a}n\,$

**Remark** $ $ For the general case (and its fractional viewpoint) see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242)

Comment: Here $\,c\neq 0\ $ (usually by convention for moduli)

Comment: So having this $\frac{15}{5} \equiv \frac{x}{5} \equiv$ -> $3 \equiv \frac{x}{5}$ (mod 2) essentially I would be searching for a number that when divided by $5$ gives $1$ in modulo $2$ and that number would be a solution in modulo $10$ as well. But if I were to utilize multiplicative inverse to solve for $x$ I would get $x \equiv 15$ (mod 2) and with it I would lose the connection to the congruence in modulo $10$. Is that right?

Comment: Numbers divisible by $5$ congruent to $1$ modulo $2$ are: $5, 15, 25, 35...$ and they are all possible values of $x$. As soon as I get rid of the denominator it is no longer true.

Comment: @Michael $x\equiv 15\equiv 5\pmod{\!10}\iff x = 5+10n = 5(1+2n)\iff x\,$ is $5$ times an odd integer. You can't use inverses because $5$ isn't invertible $\!\bmod 10\ \ $

Comment: But I can multiply both sides by $5$ to get rid of denominators then I would just get $x$ to be $1$ modulo $2$. Getting rid of the denominator in this way would no longer have meaning to the first congruence?

Comment: @Michael Scaling $\,x/5 = 3 + 2n\,$ by $5$ yields $\, x = 15 + 10n,.\,$ i.e. you need to scale the modulus too to get an equivalent congruence.

Comment: Though when I said about using an inverse was for $3 \equiv \frac{x}{5}$ (mod $2$). I would get $3 \equiv x$ (mod $2$). Then the only fact we know about $x$ is that it is odd, but not that also it is a multiple of $5$.

Comment: @Michael $\,x/5\,$ (& $\,x/c\,$ in my answer) denote a *quotient in* $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ not a modular fraction. When $\,c\,$ is coprime to the modulus it will be true that you get a true (but weaker) congruence by reducing it as a fraction, e.g. $\, x/5\equiv 0\pmod{\!2}\iff 2\mid x/5\iff 5\cdot 2\mid x,\,$ but reducing it mod $2\,$ yields a weaker condition $\,x/(5\bmod 2)\equiv x\equiv 0\pmod{\!2}\iff 2\mid x.\,$ Further, generally $\,c\,$ need not be coprime to the modulus, e.g. the case $\,c=n\,$ of the answer is

$$ x \equiv an\!\!\!\pmod{\!n^2}\,\Rightarrow\, x/n \equiv a \!\!\!\pmod{\!n}$$

Comment: We can view my answer *operationally* via the [mod  Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2963932/242)  $\, cb\bmod cn = c(b\bmod n) $ 
$$\begin{align} &c\mid x\,\Rightarrow\, x\bmod cn = c(x/c\bmod n)\\
{\rm e.g.}\ \ \ &5\mid x\,\Rightarrow\, x\bmod 10 = 5(x/5\bmod 2) = 5(x\bmod 2)
\end{align}$$
Consider what the prior means in terms of the decimal units digit of an integer $x.\ \ $